# HTTP Error 500.0 with default site set to different drive

Tags: html, iis, http-error

I am working with IIS Manager 10 on WinServer 2019. 
I have set my default IIS website to a different drive (D:); **Path: D:\FirstDir\SecondDir\ThirdDir\web**. Whenever I try to browse the website from IIS **(Browse *.80 (http))**, or try to access the site via any web browser on (or off) the server hosting it, I get an **HTTP Error 500.0** – Internal Server Error.

I’ve done everything I could think of to get around this; but what is strangest to me is if I copy the supporting home page HTML to **C:\inetput\wwwroot** then change the default IIS website to that path in IIS Manager, browsing will open that initial page; but I cannot browse any of the other links within the website from the home page (because the other links are still in the **“D:\”** path).

Now, here is what is strangest to me: If I then change the default IIS website path back to **“D:\FirstDir\SecondDir\ThirdDir\web”** and browse to the website without clearing any of the browser caches, I can still open the home page of my website; but I am also able to browse any of the other links from the home page and any other pages. I am sure that when I am browsing, after resetting to the **“D-drive”** path, I’m getting the home page I want because the **C:\inetpub** path is cached; what I don’t understand is why all of the other files are accessible – no HTTP 500 or other error occur. Of course, once I clear the browser cache and try to browse the website again I go right back to getting the 500 error.

The reason for my post here is that I am trying to resolve the HTTP 500 error. I’ve checked the logs and they provide little or no detail. I’ve tried enabling “Failed Request Tracing” but nothing gets written to the trace file. I have even gone so far as to add the \IIS-IUSR user to “D:” and all of the folders in the path.
**Please Note** all of the files I am using at this point are simple HTML.

A few other details that may be helpful from the error page Detailed Error Information:
Module: DefaultDocumentModule
Notification: ExecuteRequestHandler
Handler: StaticFile
Error Code: 0x80070002
Logon Method: Anonymous
Logon User: Anonymous

Can anyone please help me in trouble-shooting this?
One other point to note: the D: drive mentioned above is a VHD.

Comment: what permissions do you have now for all folders&files&subs?

Comment: What kind of drive is drive D? IIS does not support mapped drives, https://blog.lextudio.com/the-most-common-technologies-not-supported-by-microsoft-8675c409bde2

Comment: @Dongdong, IIS_IUSRS has Read & execute, List folder contents, Read and Write

Comment: @LexLi, That is something I meant to include in the post but forgot to. The drive is Virtual; that is, a virtual drive; and the server hosting IIS is a virtual machine.

Comment: I doubt how many users still use physical servers. VHD is OK, as long as you don't use mapped drives. Try to use Process Monitor to see what files are being accessed by IIS (w3wp.exe) when the error occurs, and it might tell why 0x8007002 is returned.

Comment: I've tracked w3wp.exe in Process Monitor. None of the operations are returning 0x8007002. I am seeing NAME NOT FOUND and PATH NOT FOUND as the result for paths referencing favicon.ico and WPAD.DAT.
Other than that, I do see an INVALID PARAMETER result for  aDeviceIoControl operation. The detail for that is "Control: IOCTL_MOUNTDEV_QUERY_DEVICE_NAME".
This was all being set up as a proof of concept for someone who wants up upgrade their server. They want to make sure their site will run on the new OS. I'm thinking that I should just do the POC on the C: drive and work the problem from there.